# Hypertune xgboost to dealing with imbalanced dataset

Tags: xgboost, class-imbalance, hyperparameter-tuning

My training data has extremely **class imbalanced** {0:872525,1:3335} with 100 features. I use xgboost to build classification model with bayessian optimisation to hypertune the model in range
`{learning rate:(0.001,0.1), min_split_loss:(0.10), max_depth:(3,70), min_child_weight:(1:20), max_delta_step:(1,20), subsample:(0:1), colsample_bytree:(0.5,1), lambda:(0,10), alpha:(0,10), scale_pos_weight:(1,262), n_estimator:(1,20)}`.

I also use binary:logistics as the objective model and roc_auc as the metrics with booster gbtree.
The cross validation score is 82.5%.
However, when I implemented the model to the testing data I got the score only
Roc_auc: 75.2%, pr_auc: 15%, log_loss: 0.046, and confusion matrix: [[19300 7],[103 14]].
I need helping to find the best way to increase the true possitive with tolerance false positive until 3 times actual positive.

Answer (score 1):

Given an imbalanced dataset and focusing on **increasing your true positive rate**, it is quite relevant to use the right **evaluation metric** (the one used to validate the model being trained on each evaluation round).

In this case, I recommend you use **Precision-Recall AUC instead of ROC AUC,** so you force your model to focus on the minority class.
A nice post about it can be found [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/roc-curves-and-precision-recall-curves-for-imbalanced-classification/)

Another points to take into account could be:

- **increase** the **range** of possible **number of tree estimators** in your hyperparameter tuning process
- set the scale_pos_weight at about your (majority class samples number)/(minority class samples number)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried to change the cross validation metrics to Precision-Recall AUC and got score 14%, but no significant changes on testing score. I also tried to change the objective model to be 'rank:map' but got worse result. Any other idea?

Comment: I see your number of trees range between 1 and 20, you can check to increase the n_estimators range of values to even hundreds or thousands, among other things. Additional checks could be made on your dataset (was it already labeled?) and preprocessing steps.

Comment: Here is the result afteroptimize the PR AUC and increase the estimators. Do you have any other idea? https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/92776/high-recall-but-too-low-precision-result-in-imbalanced-data